# Pasar elementos de un listbox a una matriz bidimensional

Tags: c#, array

Lo que quiero hacer es pasar los elementos almacenados en un listbox a un arreglo bidimensional para posteriormente calcular centroides, lo he intentado pero recorro linea por linea en lugar de elemento por elemento

```
OpenFileDialog abrir = new OpenFileDialog();
   String ruta;

        abrir.Title = "Seleccionar fichero";

        abrir.Filter = "Documentos de texto  (*.txt)|*.txt" + "|Todos los archivos (*.*)|*.* ";
        abrir.FileName = this.boxexaminar.Text;
        if (abrir.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.boxexaminar.Text = abrir.FileName;
        }

        ruta = boxexaminar.Text;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Convert.ToString(ruta));
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            showdata.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(sr.ReadLine()));

        }
        sr.Close();

        String[] matriz = new String[showdata.Items.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < showdata.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            matriz[i] = showdata.Items[i].ToString();
        }

        showclases.Text = Convert.ToString(matriz[0]);
```

Comment: Segun veo en tu código, no tienes un listBox, sino que tienes los elementos en un archivo `.txt`, estaría bien que lo aclararas en la pregunta. Por otra parte, no especificas a que te refieres como elementos ni la estructura que tiene el archivo que estas leyendo, sin saber esto nosotros no podemos ayudarte mucho, estaría bien que pusieras un poco mas de información a tu pregunta.

Comment: 2 4 3
1 3 5 5
1 5 3 2
2 6 2 1
2 5 3 0                                                                                                                  Asi esta ordenado mi txt, lo que hago primero es mandar de un txt a un listbox para poder manipular los datos ahi

Comment: @AngelSanchezLugo, lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Edita tu pregunta y agrega qué resultados esperas obtener, qué resultados tienes con este código que estás usando, qué errores tienes, etc. ya lo dijo Marc en su comentario: `sin saber esto nosotros no podemos ayudarte mucho, estaría bien que pusieras un poco mas de información a tu pregunta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas Angel,

Analizando lo que comentas en la pregunta y los comentarios posteriores, podrías hacer este proceso sin utilizar el `ListBox` `showdata`.

Según dices, tu archivo `.txt` tiene una estructura de números separados por espacios `' '`, sabiendo esto, puedes leer todas las líneas del archivo y hacer un `Split` añadiendo todos los resultados a un `List` para convertirlo a un `array` posteriormente, ya que no puedes añadir datos a un `array` directamente:

```
string[] matriz;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Convert.ToString(ruta));
List<string> list = new List<string>();
while (!sr.EndOfStream) //Mientras no llegue al final del archivo leemos
{
   list.AddRange(sr.ReadLine().Split(' '));
}
sr.Close();
matriz = list.ToArray();
```